# iOS - DetailViewController not displaying multiple entries/values from JSON

Tags: ios, iphone, json, ipad, uisplitviewcontroller

I'm creating a simple iPad app with DetailViewController. Everything works great, but when I try to use multiple level JSON, it doesn't work anymore the app crashes.

I retrieve and loop through data:

```
-(void) retrieveData{

    NSURL * url = [NSURL URLWithString:getDataURL];
    NSData * data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url];

    jsonArray = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:kNilOptions error:nil];

    fruitArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

    //loop through jsonarray
    for(int i =0;i < jsonArray.count;i++){

        NSString * cName = [[jsonArray objectAtIndex:i] valueForKey:@"cityName"];
        NSString * cFruit = [[jsonArray objectAtIndex:i] valueForKey:@"fruit"];

        //add object to fruitArray array
        [fruitArray addObject:[[Fruits alloc]initWithCityDocumentName:cName andFruit:cFruit]];

    }
    //reload table view
    [self.tableView reloadData];
}
```

using json:

```
[{
    "id": "1",
    "cityName": "London",
    "fruit":"Apple"
}, {
    "id": "2",
    "cityName": "Berlin",
    "fruit":"Pear"
}]
```

and then I set the labels(I hook them up from the storyboard/NIB):

```
- (void)setLabels{
    cityNameLabel.text = currentCity.documentName;
    fruitLabel.text = currentCity.documentFruit;
}
```

All this above work fine.

But as soon as I create multiple values in the JSON for fruits, it does not work!
New JSON:

```
[{
    "id": "1",
    "cityName": "London",
    "fruit":
        ["Apple", "Pear", "Orange", "Lemon"]
}, {
    "id": "2",
    "cityName": "Berlin",
    "fruit":
        ["Mango", "Melon", "Tomatoe", "Avocado"]
}]
```

It looks to me that I need to somehow programatically create the labels and loop over them? Basically, I need to see multiple values in the Detail View Controller for each `id`
How can I do it?

I really need a help here :(
Thank you.

**EDIT:** I was now able to create an Array rather than strings but When I'm creating buttons from them it won't let me add the title based on what's in array:

```
NSMutableArray * cFruit = [[jsonArray objectAtIndex:i] valueForKey:@"fruit"];
```

and then:

```
- (void)setLabels{


        for(int i=0;i<=currentCity.documentFruit.count;i++){

        UIButton *button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];

        [button addTarget:self
                   action:@selector(setLabels)
         forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
        //below is my error - looks like it doesn't like setting the titles from array
        [button setTitle:[currentCity.documentFruit objectAtIndex:i] forState:UIControlStateNormal];

        button.frame = CGRectMake(20.0, ButtonHeightPlusOffsetBetweenButtons * i , 280.0, 40.0);

        //Set Tag for future identification
        [button setTag:i];

        [self.view addSubview:button];

    }
    }
```

Comment: You are assigning array to string variable, and then using that as string. Take the variable as id type, then check the variable's class, if it will be string(which means the fruit key contains single fruit) then execute the current code, but if it will be array, then manage to retrieve.

Comment: Yes, you are right. But how can I use this new array to create a multiple labels or text fields?

Comment: you need to create the label or text field programmatically, to make it dynamic in number. Use loop to create them based on your fruit array count

Comment: Can you please help me how to do that?

Comment: @angular_learner why you want to create textfields programatically? If you only want to show the values use UITableView

Comment: Ok, probably that would be the best idea. How can I add these fruits in to UITableView?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here I am providing you complete code, to do so

```
#import "ViewController.h"
#import "FruitsBO.h"

@interface ViewController ()

@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITableView *tblFruit;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSMutableArray *arrFruitData;
@end

@implementation ViewController
@synthesize arrFruitData;

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

    arrFruitData = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    [self loadLocalJson];
}


-(void)loadLocalJson
{
    NSString *pathStringToLocalFile = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"Fruit" ofType:@"json"];

    NSError *deserializingError;
    NSURL *localFileURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:pathStringToLocalFile];
    NSData *contentOfLocalFile = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:localFileURL];
    NSArray *objects = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:contentOfLocalFile
                                                options:NSJSONReadingAllowFragments
                                                  error:&deserializingError];

    [self parseFruit:objects];
}


-(void)parseFruit:(NSArray *)arrFruits
{

    for (NSDictionary *dictTemp in arrFruits) {
        FruitsBO *fruit = [[FruitsBO alloc] init];

        fruit.fruitID = [dictTemp objectForKey:@"id"];
        fruit.cityName = [dictTemp objectForKey:@"cityName"];
        fruit.arrFruit = [dictTemp objectForKey:@"fruit"];

        [arrFruitData addObject:fruit];
        fruit = nil;
    }

    [self.tblFruit reloadData];
}

#pragma mark - TableView Delegate -
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    return [self.arrFruitData count];
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    FruitsBO *obj = [self.arrFruitData objectAtIndex:section];
    return [obj.arrFruit count];
}

-(CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    return 50;
}

- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return 30;
}

- (NSString *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView titleForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    FruitsBO *obj = [self.arrFruitData objectAtIndex:section];
    return obj.cityName;
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *simpleTableIdentifier = @"fruitIdentifier";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:simpleTableIdentifier];

    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:simpleTableIdentifier];
    }

    FruitsBO *objTemp = [self.arrFruitData objectAtIndex:indexPath.section];

    cell.textLabel.text = [objTemp.arrFruit objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    return cell;
}

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    [tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:YES];
}


- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

@end
```

Here my Json

```
 [{
  "id": "1",
  "cityName": "London",
  "fruit":
  ["Apple", "Pear", "Orange", "Lemon"]
  }, {
  "id": "2",
  "cityName": "Berlin",
  "fruit":
  ["Mango", "Melon", "Tomatoe", "Avocado"]
  },{
  "id": "2",
  "cityName": "Austin",
  "fruit":
  ["Mango"]
  }]
```

Here my output

[image: Output]

Comment: I like your solution, but I'd like to keep it what I currently have. I was able to create an array though but I'm unable to set the button title :( any advice?

Comment: Debug your code and check about the data in the array

Comment: I've solved it. I had to change the i=1 instead of i=0 in the for loop for some strange reason.

Answer (score 1):

The fruitArray array is a local variable in your method. It is never stored anywhere. Whatever you put into it, it will never have any effect.

BTW.

Use a for loop like for (NSDictionary* dict in jsonArray), avoiding the slow indexing operation every time.

You assume that the key fruit contains a string, when it contains an array. That is going to crash your program sooner or later.

Don't use valueForKey, use objectForKey. Eventually you will get very surprising results with valueForKey.

Answer (score 1):

After you updated your JSON, you receive not NSString object, but NSArray for the:

`NSString * cFruit = [[jsonArray objectAtIndex:i] valueForKey:@"fruit"];`

So you need to do something like this:

```
NSArray *fruitsArray  = [[jsonArray objectAtIndex:i] valueForKey:@"fruit"];
NSString *cFruit = [fruitsArray componentsJoinedByString:@","];
```

Comment: I edited my question, I now cannot be seem to be able to set the button title from looping over the array